# Time being a mediator of sort but planned on used time varying cox ph model?

Tags: panel-data, cox-model, biostatistics, mediation, epidemiology

I am working on a project where literature has traditionally treated the exposure as a time-dependent exposure and used a time varying cox ph model.

During the logistic, and normal cox PH analysis where I treat the exposure as fixed I get a protective result. As soon as I test it using a time-varying cox ph model the association completely changes in an opposite direction.

Looking at the potential casual pathway, I believe that my exposure based on its eventual change or no-change of status can have an effect of what treatments or clinical follow up is done, and therefore have an effect on the outcome.

In that case wouldn’t time kind of work as a proxy for a mediator? When I looked at my exposure and the number of tests done, the number of tests is a potential mediator between the exposure and outcome (doing a straight forward a,b, and c’ analysis).

I’m worried the time-varying cox ph model isn’t the right choice for a model.but it’s what everyone uses for this research.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!